# Login problems with headless firefox and Geb / Selenium

Tags: linux, firefox, selenium, geb, headless-browser

I have problem with a groovy (Geb) script accessing a website and it's login mechanism. On a Mac and a PC with non-headless Firefox all is working well. On a headless linux (Debian or Ubuntu) it does not work - I tried on a AWS micro & small as well as a Raspberry Pi.

On the headless machines the script can connect to the server and I can print details of the page but it looks like the login has no effect.

I installed Firefox and XVFB with apt-get. Do I have to "activate" session handling or a cookie store for login to work?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything special for a headless setup, it should work the same way it does on a non-headless box so I would blame your test box setup here.

Did you use `GebReportingSpec` and had a look at the screenshots to see what the headless browser is seeing during a test?

Comment: I didn't use GebReportingSpec but I made screenshots using xwd on a Firefox started in the shell (not via Geb). In Geb I just printed the body as text. I will look into using GebReportingSpec to make screenshots - maybe I can find a clue.